# здравствуйте, я пишу змейку на python, с помощью pygame.get.event() но она не двигается

Tags: python, pygame

```
if event.type == pygame.KEY_D and dirs["w"]:
  if event.key == pygame.K_w:
    dx, dy = 0, -1 
    dirs = {"w": True,"s": True,"a": False,"d": True, }
  if event.key == pygame.K_s and dirs["s"]:
       dx, dy = 0, 1
       dirs = {"w": False,"s": True,"a": True,"d": True, }
  if event.key == pygame.K_a and dirs["a"]:
      dx, dy = -1, 0
      dirs = {"w": True,"s": True,"a": True,"d": False, }
  if event.key == pygame.K_d and dirs["d"]:
      dx, dy = 1, 0
      dirs = {"w": True,"s": True,"a": False,"d": True, }
```

dx - направление движения по X
dy - направление движения по Y

я нажимаю на клавиши но змея не двигается.
я пробовал писать с помощью "key = pygame.key.get_pressed()" но змея почти не реагировала.

Comment: У вас условия событий обработки клавиш работает? Если да, то попробуйте увеличивать или уменьшать по x и по y на 1 единицу. Например, вместо `dx, dy = 0, 1` - > `dy+=1`. То есть, увеличивайте координату, а не присваивайте тоже значение.

Comment: большое вам спасибо!!!

Comment: написал в качестве ответа мой совет.

Answer (score 1):

> я нажимаю на клавиши но змея не двигается.

В данных строках `dx, dy = 0, 1` вы присваиваете значение числа, но при последующих обработках в условии к переменной будет присваиваться то же значение. Поэтому вам необходимо именно увеличивать или уменьшать значение переменной. Например, `dx, dy = 0, 1` - > `dy += 1`.

Ещё, я бы посоветовал использовать конструкцию `if elif else`, вместо `if if else`, тем самым у каждого условия будет цепь значений 'иначе, если', где в конце цепи условий будет одно 'иначе'.